Mapstruct Mapping from Resultset
I am attempting to use Mapstruct to map a DTO from a ResultSet.
This is not directly possible without using expresson in the @Mapping annotation like this:
    @Mapping(target="name", expression = "java(rs.getString(\"propName\"))")
    @Mapping(target="value", expression = "java(rs.getString(\"propValue\"))")
    NameValuePair map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;

This is an ugly solution. However, the Mapstruct developers have decided they will not provide direct support for ResultSet mapping (source).
Is it possible to use Mapstruct @Context and qualifiedByName to do something like this (this doesn't work because ResultSet doesn't have a field named "source")?
     // doesn't work, source doesn't exist on ResultSet
    @Mapping(target="name", source="name", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
    @Mapping(target="value", source="value", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
    NameValuePair map(String source, @Context ResultSet rs);

    @Named("stringValue")
    default String stringValue(String source, @Context ResultSet resultSet) {

        try {
            String result = resultSet.getString(source);
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null; // no, I'm not really going to return null
        }
    }

I've looked for an easy explanation in the Mapstruct reference guide, but nothing is jumping out at me.
Can anyone help?
EDIT 2: Implementation of NameValuePair
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NameValuePair {

    private String name;
    private String value;
    
    // convenience constructor for going from a Map<String, Object> but
    // you're sure value is a string
    public NameValuePair(Object name, Object value) {
        this((String) name, (String) value);
    }

}


EDIT: To you anonymous people voting to close my question, why don't you tell me what's wrong with it?

Your target has to be a property in your output object, in your case, it is NameValuePair. Meaning to say, both "name" and "value" are String properties in this class.
Can you provide a snippet of that class? Additionally, can you also provide a snippet of your ResultSet.getString(String source) method?
Edit: You mapped your source wrongly. You should map it as so:
@Mapping(target="name", source="source", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
@Mapping(target="value", source="source", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
NameValuePair map(String source, @Context ResultSet rs);

To further illustrate this mapping, imagine:
@Getter
public class Source {
    private String name;
}

A Mapstruct mapper for above class would then be:
@Mapping(target="name", source="source.name", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
@Mapping(target="value", source="source.name", qualifiedByName = "stringValue")
NameValuePair map(Source source, @Context ResultSet rs);

Or alternatively:
@Mapping(target="name", source="source", qualifiedByName = "qualifySource")
@Mapping(target="value", source="source", qualifiedByName = "qualifySource")
NameValuePair map(Source source, @Context ResultSet rs);

with its @Named method:
@Named("qualifySource")
default String stringValue(Source source, @Context ResultSet resultSet) {

    try {
        String result = resultSet.getString(source.getName());
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}


Added the class per your request. I'm aware of the normal was a @Mapping works with source and target attributes.

@Abra I simply have insufficient reputation to comment. I have edited with my answer according to OP's edit

@Abra for one, I did edit my original question with the details. Two, your answer is rude and an example of the toxic mess Stack Overflow has become While their answer did not solve my issue, they took the time to attempt an answer, and I upvoted their comment out of appreciation for them taking the time to post it.
